# Not Detecting Tap on image view

Tags: iphone, xcode, uiscrollview, uiimageview, uigesturerecognizer

I have an application in which i am calling image from URL in image view. Image view is add as subview of scroll view. In my implementation file i have use this code

```
    - (void)loadView {
    [super loadView];


        // add gesture recognizers to the image view
    UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)];
    UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)];

    [doubleTap setNumberOfTapsRequired:2];
    [twoFingerTap setNumberOfTouchesRequired:2];


    NSURL *imgUrl=[[NSURL alloc] initWithString:@"http://www.deviantart.com/download/80153093/Sexy_Kabuto_by_dark_tarou.jpg"];                 
    NSData *imgData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:imgUrl];
    UIImage *img = [UIImage imageWithData:imgData];
    imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:img];



    // set the tag for the image view
    [imageView setTag:ZOOM_VIEW_TAG];



    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [imageView addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];

    [singleTap release];
    [doubleTap release];
    [twoFingerTap release];

    [self.imageScrollView addSubview:imageView];
    [imgUrl release]; 

    // calculate minimum scale to perfectly fit image width, and begin at that scale
    float minimumScale = [imageScrollView frame].size.width  / [imageView frame].size.width;
    [imageScrollView setMinimumZoomScale:minimumScale];
    [imageScrollView setZoomScale:minimumScale];
    NSLog(@"%d",imageView.tag);
}
```

When i run on simulator then it did not detect tap recognizer. In console window it show this message

> 2011-08-01 10:01:46.999 ImageScroll[443:1907] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4e412d0 of class UIView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking
>   Unable to access variable "doubleTap"
>   "
>   Unable to access variable "singleTap"
>   Unable to access variable "doubleTap"
>   Unable to access variable "doubleTap"

What is error in this code so that it show this type of message.

Comment: try this :- [self.view sendsubviewtoback : yourscrollView]; 
[yourscrollview bringsubviewtofront:imageview];
 may b your scrollView come infront of yourImageview so it not take touch.... try tp tap once after removing scrollview so you may get clear is it problem related to ScrollView or not.

Comment: This message appear cause when u not call you thread and not initialize autoreleasepool... and release it when ur function complete..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try autoreleasing instead of immediately releasing like this:

```
//EDIT:1
NSAutoreleasePool *pool = [[NSAutoreleasePool alloc] init];
UITapGestureRecognizer *singleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleSingleTap:)] autorelease];
UITapGestureRecognizer *doubleTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleDoubleTap:)] autorelease];
UITapGestureRecognizer *twoFingerTap = [[[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(handleTwoFingerTap:)] autorelease];
//EDIT:2
[pool release];
```

and then comment out the lines

```
[singleTap release];
[doubleTap release];
[twoFingerTap release];
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: it is not working. it show this message 2011-08-01 10:01:46.999 ImageScroll[443:1907] * __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4e412d0 of class UIView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Comment: Check it out. I have edited my answer. Please check line below `//EDIT:1` and `//EDIT:2`

Comment: i didn't show any msg on  console but it not execute. When i upload this view then terminate program without any execution

Comment: @ram: try debugging and see where actually it crashes

Comment: in my code tap also not detected. when i tap on image then not happened any event.

Comment: i debug and place [pool release]; in end of function but it show same msg in console. 2011-08-01 11:49:59.246 ImageScroll[1118:1b07] *** __NSAutoreleaseNoPool(): Object 0x4e33900 of class UIView autoreleased with no pool in place - just leaking

Comment: What happened? can u tell me what i do?

Answer (score 4):

Have you checked "UserInteractionEnabled"? I believe it is NO by default. (In UIView the default value is YES)

Comment: i have do enable that but i get still this problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:singleTap];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:doubleTap];
    [self.view addGestureRecognizer:twoFingerTap];
```